# Proper way to implement a User record with id vs _id

Tags: mongodb, express, graphql, schema, apollo-server

I am having trouble understanding the proper way to implement a MongoDB User record type, to use with GraphQL.  Specifically, it has to do with the user id.

I would like to be able to query for a user record and get a user id as 'id'. MongoDB records have a _id by default.

How do I accomplish this?

do I have to define the user record as:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
}
```

Should I then populate the 'id' field on my own when creating a record?

Or should I just use the _id as a user id? if so, how do I query it? I get issues saying that I cannot query it. I think because it's not in the typedef.

Comment: You need to map this in your application. If you are using a framework, see if it supports such mapping.

Comment: I am using: apollo-server-express, passport, graphql, and mongodb. I do notice that mongodb has the concept of 'virtual'.  but I'm not sure how to get it to work with mapping a graphql typeDef with a mongoDb schema. I was hoping not having to store the id as a string since _id already exists.

Comment: no tutorials about that? not already resolved problem? really?

Comment: It most likely is. But I have been working on this for the past couple of days. People do it many different ways, with different servers, etc.  I was able to get it to work by declaring the id in it's own 'id' field, and copying the _id value once I created it. It's not really answering my question though. since I am now duplicating the _id into id.

Comment: Which one of the libraries you are using does graphql to mongodb mapping?

Comment: @D.SM, i am using mongoose.  I was trying to use the 'virtuals' method. but I gave up and instead just copied _id into id when creating a new user. not the answer. but i guess it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using TypeGraphQL along with TypeORM, and there you can create mapping by using decorators:

```
  @Field(type => ID!, { name: 'id' })
  @Column({ type: '_id', nullable: false, unique: true })
  public _id: string;
```